# Column wise sum required

Tags: java, jsp

```
         abcd   Dy  Ff  ss  Pre C   q
oops       8    0   0   0   0   2   0
GROUP C1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
GROUP C2    0   0   0   0   0   1   0
GROUP D1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
GROUP D2    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
GROUP E     0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

i have got out put as above , oops is one arraylist , Group C1 to E is result got from vector

I'm trying to get sum column wise like

```
TOTAL   8   0   0   0   0   3   0
```

I'm not getting any idea how to achieve , thank you in advance.

i have tried some thing like to get the values .

```
int j=1;
  for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
         out.print(((ArrayList)oRoleList.get(i)).get(j));
    }     

int q=2;
for(int w=0;w<=5;w++)
    {
      out.println(((ArrayList)(Vector)oBandList.get(w)).get(q));
    }
```

but I'm not get exaclty how to get sum columnwise

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: Please dont downvote , please help me out as im trying this from morning but not able to achieve :(

Comment: @MukulGoel  i have posted what i have tried, its not that i havent tried, im not getting any more ideas

Comment: What is oRoleList and oBandList?

Comment: Why do you cast an object _twice_ each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `oops == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`, and vector is `v == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} // 3 ROWS` (Did I get you correctly?), and `ROWS == 3`, and `columns == 6`. Then `accumulator = oops[position]`, i.e. we init it to the corresponding `oops` entry and you can do

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    accumulator += v[position + i * COLUMNS]
}
```

So, if you need sum in third column: `accumulator == oops[2] == 3` on the initial phase and then you do `accumulator += v[2] // == 3` and so on.
Just change the code to fit your values and go.